# Scrapy middleware setup

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to access public proxy using scrapy to get some data. I get the following error when i try to run the code:

> ImportError: Error loading object 'craiglist.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': No module named middlewares

I've created `middlewares.py` file with following code:

```
import base64
# Start your middleware class
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    # overwrite process request
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # Set the location of the proxy
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://124.200.36.150:8118"
```

settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'craiglist.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
}
```

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Please show your directory structure.

Comment: ok so middlewares.py is in C:\Users\Downloads\craiglist\craiglist\spiders and settings.py in C:\Users\Downloads\craiglist\craiglist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this setup, you need to move `middlewares.py` one level up into `craiglist` package.